# Xamarin how to solve accessibility content labeling problem?

Tags: android, xamarin, accessibility, google-play-console, xamarin-community-toolkit

When i upload a relese to Google Play Console, after internal testing y have a warning (Accessibility => Content labeling) associated to this component.

`<ImageButton .../>`

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/accessibility) the recomendation is use **android:contentDescription**

Then i add **xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"**
and:

`<ImageButton android:contentDescription="bla bla" .../>`

But i get an error: *The property contentDescription was not found in type ImageButton.*

I try to use **xct:SemanticEffect.Description** and i have not compiler error but in Google Play Console i still see the warning.

**More Information:**

Full component code:

```
<ImageButton BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="5" xct:SemanticEffect.Description="abrir menú" Clicked="OnBackButtonClicked" >
    <ImageButton.Source>
        <FontImageSource FontFamily="FAL" Glyph="&#xf057;" Color="{StaticResource Gray3}" Size="25"/>
    </ImageButton.Source>
</ImageButton>
```

[Google Play Console - Pre-launch report details - Accesibility tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1RKX.png)

[Content labeling warning for this component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjUv4.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the warning? Have you install the toolkit package and use it correctly?

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT yes i have the package installed correctly.

Comment: The `contentDescription` is for Android Layout. But your xaml is used for Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: well, how in xamarin.form i add a properties for avoid this warning?

Comment: As i know, we could not add Android descriptions to xamarin forms elements.

Comment: @Genry Like what i said in the comments. `xct:SemanticEffect.Description` should work after you installed toolkit package. But `android:contentDescription` could not be used in Xamarin.Forms contentpage xaml. You could use `android:contentDescription` in Xamarin.Android layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out, you cannot add `android:contentDescription="bla bla"` directly to the `ImageButton` one is from the Android platform, the latter is on the Xamarin.Forms level.

If you use the Xamarin Community Toolkit and apply the `SemanticEffect.Description="bla bla"` that should translate into the `contentDescription` on Android. If that is not the case, I would be curious to know what the exact warning is that you get after applying it.

Comment: i added some info (**More Information**) to question. thank for your help

Comment: I attempted adding the SemanticEffect.Description value to my controls that the Google Play Console was complaining about, but still get the same warnings regarding "This item may not have a label readable by screen readers.", so it would appear that the XCT item does not provide a ContentDescription addition.